# Passing objects to client using Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller

Ok so I'm using Node and Angular to build a web application that is going to be fairly large with multiple pages and dynamic data being displayed on each page.
I'm wondering what the best way organizationaly speaking, for me to pass a object to the UI.  Something like this:

```
app.get('/page', function(req, res){
        // process data for /page based on url parameters
        // pass data to a file page.html (request, write before showing..?)
        // display page.html
    });
```

So I think I could do this by actually writing the raw html on the server side but I was wondering if there is some way of doing this where I can get the data as some sort of request from the client side.  I'm very new to node so if anyone has any recommended libraries for MVC would appreciate it!

Comment: Never write raw html on server side. My recommendation is to use RestApi,   it is the practice I use for all my current projects and I no more face this kinds of issues you have now.

Comment: So RestApi means client makes a request to a local url ex mysite.com/api?page="index"&getDataParmams=params?  Then this would return some sort of json that the client can parse..?  smart..

Comment: Yes exactly, you can find more here: http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html

Comment: Since you're using Angular for the front end, I take it you're building a SPA? Are you using any frameworks on top of node?

Comment: I am not building a single page app, it will have lots of pages down the road.  I'm mostly playing around with technologies to see what works best and what I want to use.  Why would angular be for SPA projects?  Seems like I could serve up different web pages with no issues..

Comment: Well, Angular is built for SPA projects, most of its functionality and features are geared towards being a SPA. Most Node and Angular projects are single page applications. The Angular client just consumes API's endpoints built on Node.